# Angular 6 reactive form to populate table in other component

Tags: html, angular

I have a reactive form in Angular 6. I would like to get the inputted data from that form and populate a table in another component view. This is more of a how to question? My code looks like this so far: The form needs to populate the table with the inputs somehow. Please excuse that the form fields may not match the table fields yet, like I said I am looking at how this can be done from a development point of view.

**Form .html**

```
<!--Form-->
    <form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="serviceForm" (ngSubmit)="serviceForm.value()">
      <div class="form-group mb-8">
        <div class="col-3 col-sm-12">
          <label class="form-label" for="u_caller_id">On behalf of this user: <sub class="text-secondary">*</sub></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-12">
          <select formControlName="u_caller_id" class="form-select" required>
            <option *ngFor="let user of users" [ngValue]="user">
              {{ user.id }}
            </option>
          </select>
          <div *ngIf="serviceForm.get('u_caller_id').errors && (serviceForm.get('u_caller_id').touched || serviceForm.get('u_caller_id').dirty)">
            <div *ngIf="serviceForm.get('u_caller_id').hasError('required')" class="mt-2 mb-2">
              <h6 class="text-error">This field is required</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group mb-8">
        <div class="col-3 col-sm-12">
          <label class="form-label" for="u_destination_country">Your location: <sub class="text-secondary">*</sub></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-12">
          <select formControlName="u_destination_country" class="form-select">
            <option *ngFor="let state of countries" [ngValue]="state">
              {{ state.name }}
            </option>
          </select>
          <div *ngIf="serviceForm.get('u_destination_country').errors && (serviceForm.get('u_destination_country').touched || serviceForm.get('u_destination_country').dirty)">
            <div *ngIf="serviceForm.get('u_destination_country').hasError('required')" class="mt-2 mb-2">
              <h6 class="text-error">This field is required</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group mb-8">
        <div class="col-3 col-sm-12">
          <label class="form-label" for="u_requester_phone_number">Phone number: <sub class="text-secondary">*</sub></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-12">
          <input class="form-input" type="text" id="u_requester_phone_number" placeholder="Enter phone number" type="number"
            formControlName="u_requester_phone_number" required>
          <div *ngIf="serviceForm.get('u_requester_phone_number').errors && (serviceForm.get('u_requester_phone_number').touched || serviceForm.get('u_requester_phone_number').dirty)">
            <div *ngIf="serviceForm.get('u_requester_phone_number').hasError('required')" class="mt-2 mb-2">
              <h6 class="text-error">This field is required</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group mb-8">
        <div class="col-3 col-sm-12">
          <label class="form-label" for="u_serial_number">Device/Asset: <sub class="text-secondary">*</sub></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-12">
          <select formControlName="u_serial_number" class="form-select" required>
            <option *ngFor="let device of devices" [ngValue]="device">
              {{ device.id }}
            </option>
          </select>
          <div *ngIf="serviceForm.get('u_serial_number').errors && (serviceForm.get('u_serial_number').touched || serviceForm.get('u_serial_number').dirty)">
            <div *ngIf="serviceForm.get('u_serial_number').hasError('required')" class="mt-2 mb-2">
              <h6 class="text-error">This field is required</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group mb-8">
        <div class="col-3 col-sm-12">
          <label class="form-label" for="subject">Subject: <sub class="text-secondary">*</sub></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-12">
          <input class="form-input" type="text" id="subject" placeholder="Enter subject" type="text" formControlName="subject"
            required>
          <div *ngIf="serviceForm.get('subject').errors && (serviceForm.get('subject').touched || serviceForm.get('subject').dirty)">
            <div *ngIf="serviceForm.get('subject').hasError('required')" class="mt-2 mb-2">
              <h6 class="text-error">This field is required</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h6 class="text-gray mt-2">Please note maximum length is 80 characters.</h6>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="form-group mb-8">
        <div class="col-3 col-sm-12">
          <label class="form-label" for="describe">Please describe your issue:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 col-sm-12">
          <textarea class="form-input" id="describe" placeholder="Describe your issue" rows="3" formControlName="issue"></textarea>
          <h6 class="text-gray mt-2">The more information you can provide here, the easier time the organization will
            have in diagnosing and resolving your issue.</h6>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="columns col-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="column col-10 col-sm-6 text-right">
          <button class="btn btn-link">Cancel</button>
        </div>
        <div class="column col-2 col-sm-6">
          <a routerLink="/incident"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!serviceForm.valid">Submit</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <!-- form -->
```

**form .ts file**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-service-request',
  templateUrl: './service-request.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./service-request.component.scss']
})
export class ServiceRequestComponent implements OnInit {

  serviceForm;

  countries = [
    {name: 'Choose an option'},
    {name: 'United Kingdom',},
    {name: 'United States of America',},
    {name: 'Russia',},
    {name: 'Moscow',},
    {name: 'Africa',},
  ];

  users = [
    {id: 'Select an option',},
    {id: '1',},
    {id: '2',},
    {id: '3',},
  ];

  devices = [
    {id: 'Select an option',},
    {id: '1',},
    {id: '2',},
    {id: '3',},
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.serviceForm = new FormGroup({
      u_caller_id: new FormControl(this.users[0], Validators.required),
      u_destination_country: new FormControl(this.countries[0], Validators.required),
      u_requester_phone_number: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      u_serial_number: new FormControl(this.devices[0], Validators.required),
      subject: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(5),
        Validators.maxLength(10)
      ])),
      issue: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    });
  }

  onSubmit(serviceForm) {
    console.log("Service form submitted");
  }

}
```

**table.html**

```
     <table class="table table-striped table-hover mb-10">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Serial Number</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <!--<th>Building</th>-->
            <th>Floor</th>
            <th>Address Line 1</th>
            <th>Postal code</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="" *ngFor="let incident of incidents">
            <td><input type="radio" name="gender">
              <i class="form-icon mr-5"></i>{{incident.u_serial_number}}</td>
            <td>{{incident.u_product_name}}</td>
            <td>{{incident.u_address_floor}}</td>
            <td>{{incident.u_address_line_1}}</td>
            <td>{{incident.u_address_post_code}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

**table.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-service-incident',
  templateUrl: './service-incident.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./service-incident.component.scss']
})
export class ServiceIncidentComponent implements OnInit {

  incident = [ 
    {u_serial_number: 'E745K100200', u_product_name: 'MP2355 Black and white', u_address_floor: '2', u_address_line_1: '11 Rue De Cambrai', u_address_post_code: '75019'},
    {u_serial_number: 'E745K100200', u_product_name: 'MP2355 Black and white', u_address_floor: '2', u_address_line_1: '11 Rue De Cambrai', u_address_post_code: '75019'},
    {u_serial_number: 'E745K100200', u_product_name: 'MP2355 Black and white', u_address_floor: '2', u_address_line_1: '11 Rue De Cambrai', u_address_post_code: '75019'},
    {u_serial_number: 'E745K100200', u_product_name: 'MP2355 Black and white', u_address_floor: '2', u_address_line_1: '11 Rue De Cambrai', u_address_post_code: '75019'},
    {u_serial_number: 'E745K100200', u_product_name: 'MP2355 Black and white', u_address_floor: '2', u_address_line_1: '11 Rue De Cambrai', u_address_post_code: '75019'},
    {u_serial_number: 'E745K100200', u_product_name: 'MP2355 Black and white', u_address_floor: '2', u_address_line_1: '11 Rue De Cambrai', u_address_post_code: '75019'},
  ];

  incidents=this.incident;


  constructor(private service: ServicenowService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getAll().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('Result - ', data);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: you should use some kind of service / store to pass your data through.  or work with Subjects in RxJS

Answer (score 0):

I would use a subject this task
create a new service (using cli ng g s dataService) and inside the service

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
dataSubj:Subject<any> = new Subject()
```

form.ts:

```
constructor(private dataS: dataService){}
onSubmit(serviceForm) {
  console.log("Service form submitted");
  this.dataS.dataSubj.next(this.serviceForm.value)
}
```

inside the tables component:

```
constructor(private dataS: dataService){}
ngOninit(){
   this.dataS.formComponent.datasubj.subscribe(res=>{
     console.log(res)
     //add res to the table
   })
}
```

Hope this helps to start

Comment: Thanks GaryB but how would I bind the data into the views?

Comment: I dont exactly know what do you mean about binding the data to the view, but
 if all the data from the form is required its only pushing it to the array.
//add res to the table
incidents.push(res)

...to keep the data for forever you need a database